# Как вывести треугольник паскаля в питоне форме как на фото

Tags: python

[image: фото]

Как вывести треугольник паскаля в питоне форме как на фото

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свой код который Вы уже сделали. И укажите какая у Вас шибка возникает, или какой результат получился вообще.  Если у Вас срочный заказ или Тестовое задание - то попытайте счастье на платных фриланс биржах. Если Вы хотите понять как вывести этот треугольник - то сделайте хоть пару неверных выводов, некоректных треугольников, или словите пару ошибок решиния которых не гуглятся за первых 5 секунд. От этого будет больше пользы чем получить  готовое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию Python заполняет свободное пространство внутри поля пробелами. Вы можете выбрать другой символ для заполнения. Его нужно указать сразу после двоеточия.Например:

```
print("{:*^20s}".format("Hallo"))
******* Hallo********
```

https://www.8host.com/blog/formatirovanie-strok-v-python-3/

```
def current_row(n):
    row=list()
    for i in range(n):
        if i==0 or i==n-1:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            c_row=current_row(n-1)
            row.append(c_row[i-1]+c_row[i])
    return row

def triangle(m):
    result=list()
    for i in range(m):
        result.append(current_row(i+1))
    ### beautify
    for j in result:
        print("{:^50s}".format(str(j)))
triangle(10)
```